# How to update combo box items source from another window?

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf, mvvm, parent-child

I am working on some Hotel business application. I have a "BookingsWindow" for inserting new bookings into database. In this window there is one combo box with list of all guests in the hotel. "BookingsWindow" is a parent window. It contains one button for adding new guest. When you click on that button new winodw opens ("GuestWindow" - child window). Both windows have their own view models ("BookingsViewModel" and "GuestsViewModel"). The combo box's item source in parent window is bounded to property "Guests", which is observable collection with values from database table. My queston is, how can I update combo box items source after adding new guest from child window?

**BookingsWindow.xaml**

```
<ComboBox Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Left" IsEditable="True"   IsTextSearchEnabled="True" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Guests}" Margin="119,10,0,0" Name="cbGuest" Padding="3,1,1,1" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=Guest}" TextSearch.TextPath="Name" VerticalAlignment="Top" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Width="141" FontFamily="Times New Roman" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="14">
        <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock DataContext="{Binding}" Text="{MultiBinding StringFormat='\{0\} ', Bindings={Binding Path=Name}}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ComboBox>
<Button BorderBrush="Black" Command="{Binding Path=btnAddGuest}" Content="Novi Gost" FontFamily="Times New Roman" FontWeight="Bold" Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Left" IsDefault="True" Margin="266,10,0,0" Name="btnNewGuest" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="62" />
```

**BookingsViewModel.cs**

```
    private ObservableCollection<ServiceReference1.tblGuest> guests;
    public ObservableCollection<ServiceReference1.tblGuest> Guests
    {
        get
        {
            return guests;
        }
        set
        {
            guests = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Guests");               
        }
    }

    public ICommand _btnAddGuest;
    public ICommand btnAddGuest
    {
        get
        {
            if (_btnAddGuest == null)
            {
                _btnAddGuest = new DelegateCommand(delegate()
                {
                    try
                    {
                        GuestsViewModel gst = new GuestsViewModel();

                        Guests guest = new Guests();
                        guest.ShowDialog();
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        Trace.WriteLine("working...", "MyApp");
                    }
                });
            }
            return _btnAddGuest;
        }
```

**Guests.xaml**

```
<Button Content="Dodaj" FontFamily="Times New Roman" FontWeight="Bold" Height="36" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,402,0,0" Name="btnAddGuest" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="62" IsDefault="True" Command="{Binding Path= btnAddGuest}" />
```

**btnAddGuest** is a command for adding new guest to database("tblGuests")

**GuestsViewModel**

```
    private ServiceReference1.tblGuest guest;
    public ServiceReference1.tblGuest Guest 
    {
        get 
        {
            return guest;
        }
        set 
        {
            guest = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Guest");
        }
    }       



    public ICommand _btnAddGuest;
    public ICommand btnAddGuest 
    {
        get
        {
            if (_btnAddGuest == null)
            {
                _btnAddGuest = new DelegateCommand(delegate()
                {
                    try
                    {
                        Service1Client wcf = new Service1Client();                           

                        wcf.AddGuest(Guest);
                        wcf.Close();          
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        Trace.WriteLine("working...", "MyApp");
                    }
                });
            }
            return _btnAddGuest;
        }
    }
```

**wcf.AddGuest** is a method on WCF service for adding new guests to database...

When I add new guest to database, combo box doesn't have that new guest in it's list. How to manage this?